# To use "New-SPOSite" for managing SharePointOnline on AzureAutomtion has an error

Tags: powershell

Please advise me if you had the same issue.
There is an error when I use "New-SPOSite" of Powershell command for managing SPO on AzureAutomation.

I searched a lot but there was no solution for that. Does someone have a solution or an advice?

Here is the error result I faced.

[image]

Comment: Are you really using "Tenant-Name" or are you using the name of your tenant?

Comment: no, it's dummy. Because I can not share my actual tenant name. That sample is for the explanation of the issue.

Comment: I'm using my tenant.

Comment: Your code shows `-Url ..../AutoNewSPOsite`, but the error says `-Url ".../NewSite"`.

Comment: @Theo oh I'm sorry. it's my typo because I changed some words for the explanation. But I checked again these settings, I was not able to get the desired result...

Comment: @Theo Thank you for your help. I'm investigating it still.

Comment: Could it have to do with [this](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/07/object-reference-not-set-to-instance-of-an-object-error-on-site-creation.html) maybe?

Comment: @Theo Thank you for your information! I found the solution for the issue. I needed to set "-Template" option for "New-SPOSite". According to the official site, This parameter was not mandatory, but it needed my situation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/new-sposite?view=sharepoint-ps

Comment: @Theo I have resolved it. Thank you for your effort. I'm wondering still....(^_^;)

Comment: Good find! You should post as answer because it may also help others struggling with that same problem.

Comment: @Theo Thank you for your advice! I posted my solution to the answer. you helped my issue. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It needed to set the `-Template` option for `New-SPOSite`. According to [the official site](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/new-sposite?view=sharepoint-ps), even though this parameter is not mandatory, it is required in this situation.